# Exception on transfering BigDecimal over Google Cloud Endpoints

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to transfer Articles data over cloud endpoints and the legacy application ( Android ) uses data structure that requires all the prices be in BigDecimal. Here is my Entity class:

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name = "articles")
public class Article {
    private int id;
    ....
    private BigDecimal price;


    @Id
    @Column(name = "_id")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy = "increment")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    .....

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "price", precision=7, scale=2)
    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

Using the API explorer I get the following result:

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "id": 2,
   ....
   "price": 5.00001,
   ...
  }
}
```

When trying to consume the endpoint in android using this code:

```
String accountName = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_CREDENTIALS);
GoogleAccountCredential credentials = GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience(this,
        AppConstants.AUDIENCE);
credentials.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
if(articleApiService == null) {  // Only do this once
    articleApiService = AppConstants.getApiServiceHandle(credentials);
}

CollectionResponseArticle articles = null;
try {
    articles = articleApiService.listArticles().execute();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
}
```

I get the following exception in JSONParser.java:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: key price
        at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:880)
        ...
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: key price, field private java.util.List com.example.articlesendpoint.model.CollectionResponseArticle.items
        at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:880)
        ...
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: key price, field private java.util.List com.example.articlesendpoint.model.CollectionResponseArticle.items
        at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:880)
        ...
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: key price, field private com.example.articlesendpoint.model.BigDecimal com.example.articlesendpoint.model.Article.price
        at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:880)
        ...
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expected numeric type but got class com.example.articlesendpoint.model.BigDecimal
        at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:843)
            at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:471)
            at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:780)
            at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseArray(JsonParser.java:647)
            at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:739)
            at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:471)
            at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:780)
            at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:381)
            at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:354)
            at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:87)
            at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:81)
            at com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse.parseAs(HttpResponse.java:459)
            at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
            at com.pos.android.dbsync.DBsyncService.onHandleIntent(DBsyncService.java:57)
            at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

When checking the generated endpoint client libraries there is a BigDecimal 
model class auto-generated for me that seems not recognizable to the android JSON de-serializer:

```
/*
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except
 * in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License
 * is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express
 * or implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under
 * the License.
 */
/*
 * This code was generated by https://code.google.com/p/google-apis-client-generator/
 * (build: 2015-01-14 17:53:03 UTC)
 * on 2015-02-25 at 19:50:44 UTC 
 * Modify at your own risk.
 */

package com.example.articlesendpoint.model;

/**
 * Model definition for BigDecimal.
 *
 * <p> This is the Java data model class that specifies how to parse/serialize into the JSON that is
 * transmitted over HTTP when working with the articlesendpoint. For a detailed explanation see:
 * <a href="http://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/wiki/JSON">http://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/wiki/JSON</a>
 * </p>
 *
 * @author Google, Inc.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
public final class BigDecimal extends com.google.api.client.json.GenericJson {

  /**
   * The value may be {@code null}.
   */
  @com.google.api.client.util.Key
  private java.lang.Integer scale;

  /**
   * @return value or {@code null} for none
   */
  public java.lang.Integer getScale() {
    return scale;
  }

  /**
   * @param scale scale or {@code null} for none
   */
  public BigDecimal setScale(java.lang.Integer scale) {
    this.scale = scale;
    return this;
  }

  @Override
  public BigDecimal set(String fieldName, Object value) {
    return (BigDecimal) super.set(fieldName, value);
  }

  @Override
  public BigDecimal clone() {
    return (BigDecimal) super.clone();
  }

}
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigDecimal is not a supported return type. [The supported return types are](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/paramreturn_types#supported_parameter_types):

```
java.lang.String
java.lang.Boolean and boolean
java.lang.Integer and int
java.lang.Long and long
java.lang.Float and float
java.lang.Double and double
java.util.Date
com.google.api.server.spi.types.DateAndTime
com.google.api.server.spi.types.SimpleDate
Any enum
Any array or java.util.Collection of a parameter type
```

You have a few options:

1. Use [@ApiTranformer](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations#apitransformer) - in your transformer pass in an Article and return a wrapped Article entity which represents the price values as say String
2. Forget the transformer stuff, just decorate your model and make sure your endpoint method returns the decorated type, something like

```java
public WrappedArticle(Article article) {
    price = article.getPrice().toString();
    ....
}
```

3. Annotate ***price*** with [@JsonIgnore](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.0.1/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonIgnore.html) so that the Jackson deserializer (assuming that you're using the default json factory) ignores that property, and add another property of say type String. Make sure you annotate with **@IgnoreSave** so that Objectify doesn't store it as part of your entity.

```java
@IgnoreSave
private String priceStr;
```

now you can provide the following getter:

```java
public String getPriceStr() {
  return price.toString();
}
```

This is it. Job done!